# No such file or directory: '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-ubuntu-java-bionic.list'

Tags: java, 16.10

I accidentally deleted the directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d'. 
How can I solve?

Comment: As a sidenote: Don't use 16.10. It's end of life. Upgrade to 18.04 or 18.10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/apt/sources.list.d` is owned by root, and has the permissions rwxr-xr-x

You can recreate it with

```
sudo mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d
sudo chmod 755 /etc/apt/sources.list.d
```

You will of course have to manually add all sources you want after having recreated the directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please, try this command to recreate your repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt update
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I have deleted the directory 

/etc/apt/sources.list.d 

 by mistake. Now running the command 

sudo add-apt-repository command ppa: webupd8team / java

 and i have this error 'can not find the folder'

Comment: Try this:  mkdir /etc/apt/sources.list.d